# Take a 1D list of results and convert it to a N-D xarray.DataArray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

This is how I acquire my N-D data (`func` is IRL not vectorizable):

```
import numpy
import xarray
import itertools

xs = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 100)
ys = numpy.linspace(0, 0.1, 20)
zs = numpy.linspace(0, 5, 200)

def func(x, y, z):
    return x * y / z

vals = list(itertools.product(xs, ys, zs))
result = [func(x, y, z) for x, y, z in vals]
```

I have a feeling that what I do can be simplified. I would like to put this in a `xarray.DataArray` without reshaping the data. However, this is how I do it now:

```
arr = np.array(result).reshape(len(xs), len(ys), len(zs))
da = xarray.DataArray(arr, coords=[('x', xs), ('y', ys), ('z', zs)])
```

This a simple example, but usually I work with ~10D data that I obtain by mapping a `itertools.product` (in parallel).

My question: how can I do this without reshaping my data and by using `vals` and without taking the lengths of `xs`, `ys`, and `zs`?

In a similar way to what you what do with:

```
index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples(vals, names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
df = pandas.DataFrame(result, columns=['result'], index=index)
```

**EDIT:**
This is how I solved it, inspired on the answer by @hpaulj, thanks!

```
import numpy
import xarray
import itertools

coords = dict(x=numpy.linspace(0, 10, 100),
              y=numpy.linspace(0, 0.1, 20),
              z=numpy.linspace(0, 5, 200))

def func(x, y, z):
    return x * y / z

result = [func(x, y, z) for x, y, z in itertools.product(*coords.values())]

xarray.DataArray(numpy.reshape(result, [len(i) for i in coords.values()]), coords=coords)
```

**EDIT 2**
See this issue: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1914

Comment: Noticed you edited the question, not nice. Below the answer to the original question.

Comment: The essence of my question didn't change. I just added a dimension to make it less trivial looking. Note that I said: "I work with ~10D data".

Comment: It does change the essence of the question! Also the fact that you are dividing by z certainly changes the problem very much. Decide by yourself if you want any help.

Comment: The function I put there is a trivial example. Maybe I should note that the function is not vectorizable.

Comment: You say your data is actually 10 dimensions. Suppose each array has 10 elements (low estimation based on your actual example), that gives you 10**10 values to compute. I do not think you are anywhere serious nor know where you are heading.

Comment: The computations I do usually involve 1e9 values yes, and are performed on a cluster on ~300 cores. I don't understand your downvote.

Comment: Well OK, then if func can be arbitrary complex, you cannot use Numpy primitives to compute it. "result = [func(x, y, z) for x, y, z in itertools.product(xs, ys, zs)]" should give you a substantial speedup. I downvoted because the question changed invalidating my original answer.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `reshape`? Performance or code aesthetics?

Comment: Glad you followed my advice for not actually building the list.

Comment: Out of curiosity, hat is your actual func() that requires you to do the itertools step rather than a numpy calculation?

Comment: I use `ipyparallel` and use an asynchronous mapping of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experienced `numpy` users tend to focus on removing iterative steps. Thus we've zoomed in on your `result` calculation, and view the `reshape` as something trivial.  Hence the answers so far have focused on broadcasting and calculating your function.

But I'm beginning to suspect that what's really bothering you is that

```
reshape(len(xs), len(ys), len(zs))
```

could become unwieldy if you have 10 such dimensions, not just 3.  It's not so much the calculation speed, but the effort required to type `len(..)` 10 times.  Or may be it's that the code will look ugly.

Anyways here's a way of bypassing all that typing.  The key is to collect the dimensional arrays in a list

```
In [495]: dims = [np.linspace(0,10,4), np.linspace(0,.1,3), np.linspace(0,5,5)]
In [496]: from itertools import product
In [497]: vals = list(product(*dims))
In [498]: len(vals)
Out[498]: 60
In [499]: result = [sum(ijk) for ijk in vals] # a simple func
```

Now just get the `len's` with a simple list comprehension:

```
In [501]: arr=np.array(result).reshape([len(i) for i in dims])
In [502]: arr.shape
Out[502]: (4, 3, 5)
```

Another possibility is to put the `linspace` parameters in lists right at the start.

```
In [504]: ldims=[4,3,5]
In [505]: ends=[10,.1,5]
In [506]: dims=[np.linspace(0,e,l) for e,l in zip(ends, ldims)]
In [507]: vals = list(product(*dims))
In [508]: result=[sum(ijk) for ijk in vals]
In [509]: arr=np.array(result).reshape(ldims)
```

`reshape` itself is not an expensive operation.  Usually it creates a view, which is one of the fastest things you can do with an array.

`@Divakar` hinted at this kind of solution in his deleted answer, with `*np.meshgrid(*A)` as alternative to your `product(xs,ys)`.

By the way, my answer doesn't involve `xarray` either - because I don't have that package installed.  I'm assuming that you know what you are doing when passing `arr` of that 3d shape to it, as opposed to the longer 1d array. Look at the tag numbers, 5k followers for `numpy`, 23 for `xarray`.

The `xarray` `coords` parameter could also be constructed from `dims` (with an additional list of names).

If this answer isn't to your liking, I'd suggest closing the question, and starting a new one with just the `xarray` tag.  That way you won't attract the numerous `numpy` flies.

Comment: Thank you! This inspired me :) I think making `dims` a `dict` would even be nicer, since I will be able to use the keys for the `coords` and you will preserve the names of the lists/numpy arrays.

Comment: Or use separate `dims` and `coords` parameters.  I took a minute to look up the API, http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.html

Comment: I edited my answer and added a potential solution :)

Answer (score 0):

2nd EDIT I had forgotten about einsum! If you can torture your function to fit this will be even faster (1.5ms on the timeit below)

```
result = np.einsum('i,j,k', xs, ys, 1.0 / zs)
```

You need to reshape and broadcast to the same shaped array. As Balzola says this will be VERY big if it's 10D and 100 in each direction (10**20 elements). As hpaulj says reshaping a numpy array is generally trivial, and is so in this case though broadcasting does take some work. However much less than the itertools.product() method. For your example

```
import numpy as np

xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
ys = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 20)
zs = np.linspace(0.1, 5, 200)

xn, yn, zn = len(xs), len(ys), len(zs)

xs_b = np.broadcast_to(xs.reshape(xn, 1, 1), (xn, yn, zn))
ys_b = np.broadcast_to(ys.reshape(1, yn, 1), (xn, yn, zn))
zs_b = np.broadcast_to(zs.reshape(1, 1, zn), (xn, yn, zn))

result = xs_b * ys_b / zs_b
```

using timeit as below I get the numpy computation to be 4ms and the itertools method 150ms. I think the difference would be bigger for more dimensions.

```
import timeit

init = '''
import itertools
import numpy as np

def func(x, y, z):
    return x * y / z

xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
ys = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 20)
zs = np.linspace(0.1, 5, 200)

xn, yn, zn = len(xs), len(ys), len(zs)
'''
funcs = ['''
xs_b = np.broadcast_to(xs.reshape(xn, 1, 1), (xn, yn, zn))
ys_b = np.broadcast_to(ys.reshape(1, yn, 1), (xn, yn, zn))
zs_b = np.broadcast_to(zs.reshape(1, 1, zn), (xn, yn, zn))

result = xs_b * ys_b / zs_b
''','''
vals = list(itertools.product(xs, ys, zs))
result = [func(x, y, z) for x, y, z in vals]
''']

for f in funcs:
  print(timeit.timeit(f, setup=init, number=100))
```

EDIT PS. I altered your zs to prevent the numpy warning by dividing by zero as this might have effected the timeit comparison.